# Reusing headset cups on semi-integrated headset

Tags: maintenance, headset, reuse

I purchased a used frame that didn't come with the full headset but did come with the alloy cups still installed. They are ZS44/ZS56 tapered setup. Likely Cane Creek 40-series.

The cups appear to be in perfect shape. There is no visible wear.

1. Is it worth pulling them and pressing new ones?
2. Since it's standard size bearings, am I ok using a different brand headset with the existing cups?

I'm hesitant to pop the cups if it's unnecessary. Hammering with a cup removal tool can cause unnecessary damage to the head tube (alloy frame).

Answer (score 2):

I went into the bike store with my frame in tow. I can in fact reuse the cups. It was cheaper to buy an entire ZS44/ZS56 headset than the rest of the parts without cups.

It was unclear, but apparently at some point there was more than one angle for the cups. The bike is modern enough that wasn't a concern, but they also had a tool to verify what angle the cups were.